# evaluation map and rational points

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Please help me to solve this question or introduce references that help me.

What is the definition of evaluation
map? For an scheme $X$ on an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero, the evaluation map is defined on rational points. Why?

Thank you.

Comment: I think we need more information. I know of several things that are called "the evaluation map." What context is this coming up in? Can you at least tell us the domain and range of the map?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some ambiguities in the phrasing of the question, but I'll try to answer what I think you're asking.

Suppose $X$ is an affine scheme over a field $k$, then the structure sheaf $O_X$ is a sheaf of $k$ algebras.  Each rational point $x \in X(k)$ is a morphism $\text{Spec}(k) \to X$, which also gives an associated map on global sections $O_{X}(X) \to k$.  I think this is the evaluation map you want.  For example, if $X$ is integral and $O_{X}(X)$ is finitely generated, then this map really is just the evaluation at a point on some quotient of a polynomial algebra.